# In programs compiled without CRT, is it possible to read command-line arguments via argv?

Tags: c, winapi

I've written a program to print out the command-line arguments it receives in a message box.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

int wmain(int argc, LPCWSTR argv[])
{
    for (int k = 0; k < argc; k++)
    {
        WCHAR szTemp[100];
        wsprintfW(szTemp, argv[k]); // Yes, this is unsafe. Moving on...
        MessageBoxW(0, szTemp, L"from argv", 0);
        SecureZeroMemory(szTemp, 100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I then build it with the following commands:

`cl.exe /nologo /c /Zl /W4 /MT /GS- /wd4100 test.cpp`

and

`link.exe /nologo /subsystem:CONSOLE /entry:wmain /OUT:args.exe test.obj`

Upon execution, the program runs for some time and then terminates. No message box appears.

I've verified that the analogous code using `CommandLineToArgvW` works as expected:

```
LPWSTR *szArglist;
int nArgs;

szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &nArgs);

// Error checking and cleanup elided here
for (int k = 0; k < nArgs; k++)
{
    WCHAR szTemp[100];
    wsprintfW(szTemp, szArglist[k]);
    MessageBoxW(0, szTemp, L"from CommandLineToArgvW", 0);
    SecureZeroMemory(szTemp, 100);
}
```

In my debugger I can see that the program does enter the loop, but then it seems to hit an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` inside the `wsprintfW` function. What am I missing?

Comment: A qualified guess is that the printf family of functions use variables with static storage duration internally, and if there's no CRT, those variables can't be initialized.

Comment: */entry:wmain* - the entry point of *exe* file must have signature `ULONG WINAPI ep(void*)` - nobody pass to you `(int argc, LPCWSTR argv[])` in entry point - so in place argc will be pointer to *PEB* and in place `argv` - undefined trash

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nowhere in either program is there an attempt to write to the console.

Comment: Oops, I misread, sorry

Comment: @Lisbeth FYI, you don't need `wsprintfW()` at all in this example code (especially since you are not using it correctly anyway). Just pass the parsed command-line arguments as-is directly to `MessageBoxW()`, eg: `MessageBoxW(0, argv[k], L"from argv", 0);` ... `MessageBoxW(0, szArglist[k], L"from CommandLineToArgvW", 0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard defines the behavior of `main` and its arguments. Windows does no such thing!

The official PE specification says nothing about the entrypoint function. You should assume that it is simply `void __stdcall ExeEntrypoint();`.

When using the Microsoft compiler, linker and run-time library the [linker defaults the entrypoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2019) to a function named `[w]mainCRTStartup` in console programs.

> By default, the starting address is a function name from the C run-time library. The linker selects it according to the attributes of the program, as shown in the following table.

`wmainCRTStartup` calls `GetCommandLineW` and parses the result into the `argc` & `argv` pair which it uses when it calls your `main` function.

When linking with `/entry:wmain` you remove `wmainCRTStartup` from the equation and **you** become responsible for the initialization of `argv` & `argc` and all the other tasks performed by the function (initialize globals, `atexit` etc.).

And just to lay this parameter issue to rest, I went back and tested some ancient versions and it seems you cannot trust it to be anything useful on older versions of Windows:

[image: 95,NT4,98,XP,8]

It is possible that some time after WinXP it was finalized to point to the PEB but it is not part of any official specification.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is the function signature `void __stdcall ExeEntrypoint()` (un)officially documented anywhere, or obtained via disassembly?

Comment: when function no arguments - no different (except decoration name) which calling convention use (__stdcall, __cdecl, __fastcall - all will be have the same effect). by fact system pass 1 agrument to entry point, so `int __stdcall ExeEntrypoint(void*);` more exactly, but because after `ExeEntrypoint` return control (if at all return) just `ExitThread` called - no mistakes due incorrect stack pointer after return (on *x86*)

Comment: @Lisbeth - formal `void __stdcall ExeEntrypoint()` this is wrong signature, correct `ULONG__stdcall ExeEntrypoint(void*)` but on practice no difference

Comment: @RbMm do you have a source to back up this claim of returning ULONG? And either way, returning might not end the process so it is not great advice. And yes, with no arguments the calling convention does not matter but the linker documentation on MSDN says stdcall! (This is only important for DllMain)

Comment: no, i have no src, but i view windows code - https://i.imgur.com/nsqILi2.png - this is from xp how minimum up to the latest win10. the same on x64 (here simply not visible calling convention) can belive me or check yourself. but what i say about entry point is 100%

Comment: @Anders - about `returning ULONG` - the returned value used as argument in call [`ExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitthread) (ok - `RtlExitThread` if want be more exactly). so this is ulong (or int if want). but i not say that we must return from EP. really process can not terminate if we not call `ExitProcess` direct. but i say about formal signature only. EP have 1 parameter (pointer to PEB) and return valur formal used

Comment: @RbMm It would be more interesting to go back and see what Win95 and NT3 are doing. And even if they do pass a PEB pointer, I would still be nervous about using it in a real program.

Comment: x64 variant - https://i.imgur.com/vSzSo7E.png - but src - i not responsible for windows documentation :)

Comment: @Anders - but i not say that we need **use** it. i simply say that 1 argument passed to function. we can treat it as opaque. simply in usual case between `int __stdcall fn(void*)` and `int fn()` exist critical difference in usual case on x86 - 4 byte esp will be different after return. but because just `ExitThread` called - nothing affected

Comment: also if want - look this https://i.imgur.com/e6a7z1v.png. in wdk exist *nt.lib* lib file (designed for use in boot execute apps i think) here mini crt if want and entry point of application here named as `_NtProcessStartupW@4` and `_NtProcessStartup@4` (2 entry for unicode and ansi) - are lib from microsoft wdk - this is src for claim ?

Comment: so can search in google for "NtProcessStartupW" "NtProcessStartup" - i dont know why all this not documented (reason), may be you understand this, but by fact 1 argument is present in exe entry point

Comment: More information: [WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573).

Comment: @RbMm See the link in the previous post, stdcall and "The operating system calls the function with no parameters" which is probably as close to documentation as we are going to get.

Comment: @Anders - yes, i read this. but this is false (mistake ?) if you know asm (x86/x64) - you can easy look from where and how exe entry point is called. if want - can found this info in windows internals book.. what i say - simply fact. exist 1 parameter in call. and note - i do not suggest using it, i do not suggest return from entry point (when say that this have ULONG return value) - i simply say about formal and correct **signature**. you know - documentation not always correct. here i say how is in real word.

Comment: sorry for question, i just really interested in your opinion, are you view itself that really 1 parameter used in call exe entry point ? despite what writtent in msdn, or how wmainCRTStartup() is declared. in practice, there are no differences even on x86 because just after EP return (if at all return) - call ExitThread and no matter already esp value, but formally 1 parameter really passed (checked from xp how minimum up to latest).

Comment: @RbMm I'll try to check Win95 tonight or tomorrow, then we can form an opinion whether this is a Win32 thing or a NT thing. I agree that it does not matter how the function is declared when `/entry` is used. If `/entry` is not used and you use `/nodefaultlibs` it might matter though.

Comment: but Win95 if i not mistake at all not compatible with all this. sorry but i never view this system and dont know it. but i think no any sense check here (on win95) - because another os, not compatible. assume that you write very basic app, used only ExitProcess call (without crt) - are such exe at all will be run on 95 ? check on win2000 and nt4 - already exist sense. but i only describe current state (from xp to win10)

Comment: Of course Win95 matters, if 9x does not pass a PEB pointer (9x does not technically have a PEB but it does have a process struct pointed to by the TIB(TEB)) then you can't claim that this is a Win32 feature, that would make it a NT feature. The PE format and NT4/Win95 are mostly compatible except for missing security and some other minor differences when you code to the documented Win32 API.

Comment: i not claim that this is win32 (or nt) feature. i claim (not more or less) that in [win xp, win10] exe entry point called and used as  `ULONG __stdcall ep(void* )` - called as __stdcall function with 1 argument (on practice this is pointer to PEB but i not suggest use it. simple note this fact) and return value (if ep returm but again - i not suggest return from ep) used in call `RtlExitUserThread` this is how now . i think that in win2000 also the same situation, but have not it and not view sense install this too old system.

Comment: about 95 - dont know. i even dont know if take simply modern exe with minimal import (for not use new api) - are it at all can be run on win95. in PE exist in optional header major/minor operation system versions. even dont know what need set for 95 for run. less than 4.0 i think..

Comment: @rbm: The return value is not part of the signature.

Comment: @RbMm Did you actually test on WinXP? See my picture in the updated answer. And just for the record, Win95 uses a normal PE header and the OS version is 4.0.

Comment: @Anders - oops. sorry i mistake. on xp really we have `ULONG ep()` signature - https://i.imgur.com/GWtURSf.png on vista i not look, but on win7 already exist one parameter (pointer to PEB) - https://i.imgur.com/RT25246.png

Comment: as side note *you become responsible for the initialization of argv & argc* yes. another question for what reason not use c/c++ CRT. if not use it - also exist variant  link with *nt.lib* from *wdk* - in this case small entry point from this lib `NtProcessStartup[W]` initialize for us argc, argv and env and call `[w]main`

Answer (score 3):

you use */entry:wmain* linker option - this mean that your *wmain* became entry point of *exe*. but signature of *exe* entry point must be next:

`ULONG WINAPI ep(void* peb)`

this function take from windows 1 argument (pointer to [`PEB`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa813706(v=vs.90)) structure). called as `__stdcall` (so `WINAPI` or `CALLBACK` if want) and return value (if you return from ep) used as argument for call `ExitThread`.

usually we not return from *ep* but call `ExitProcess`. but even if we return from *exe* entry point - we in current implementation can use and some another signature - say

`int wmainCRTStartup()`

despite this is wrong signature (stack pointer will be wrong after return on *x86*) this not play role in current windows implementation, because just after entry point return control - the `ExitThread` is called and nothing referenced in stack.

also possible have `void` return type, instead `int` or `ULONG` - if we not care about our thread (not process !!) return code. usually this not play any role. especially if we never return from *ep* but direct call `ExitProcess` - we can declare and `void` return type.

but anyway the signature

`int wmain(int argc, LPCWSTR argv[])`

is wrong for exe entry point - because it take 1 pointer instead *argc, argv*

so in place *argc* we will be have pointer to [`PEB`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa813706(v=vs.90)) and in place *argv* - undefined trash.

when you use *CRT* and default linker settings - the [`/entry:wmainCRTStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2019) (also note that msdn if wrong here *The parameters and return value depend on if the program is a console application, a windows application* - this is false - not depend on this)

the `wmainCRTStartup` already call your `wmain` with *argc, argv*

and finally about "arguments" of command line - what is arguments - this is already interpretation only. exist command line string, returned by [`GetCommandLineW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew). how interpret this string - already we absolute free here.

---

as alternative solution if you not want use standard c/c++ CRT but want use `wmain` we can use *NT.LIB*  and *bufferoverflowU.lib* from *WDK*

in this case you need set **`/entry:NtProcessStartupW`** or **`/entry:NtProcessStartup`** - depend from are you want use Unicode or Ansi version and implement

```
extern "C"
int __cdecl wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[ ], wchar_t *envp[ ], ULONG DebugFlags );
```

so real exe entry point will be `NtProcessStartup[W]` which call your `[w]main` with standard parse command line

Comment: So ... it's a no, then?

Comment: @Lisbeth -why no ? of course we can do all without any crt. you can use `CommandLineToArgvW` if want, you can call `GetCommandLineW` and then yourself parse command line. can design self format where not space is separator. you can do all. but you need understand - then declare `int wmain(int argc, LPCWSTR argv[])` as entry point is wrong. you can `int wmain()` declare if want as entry. or `void  __stdcall wmain(void*)` etc. but get cmd line not as input parameter in ep

Comment: @Lisbeth - i simply try explain why your first code snippet is crash - because you use *argc, argv* despite *argc* - was not count of arguments but pointer to some data structure (so very big value if interpret it as *int*) and what in place *argv* - at all undefined. so you reference random memory and got `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` as and must be. but you view that your second example is work (despite wrong and for what ?) `wsprintfW`